# in Temporal why single worker for single service is sufficient?

Tags: temporal-workflow

in Temporal why single worker for single service is sufficient? doesn't it become a bottleneck for the system to scale? does Worker a single threaded or multi-threaded process?

I have gone through the Temporal documentation but couldn't understand why single Worker per client service is sufficient.

I also tried creating different task queue for different workflows and created new worker(using workerfactory.newWorker(..) method creating 2 workers in the same process) to listen on the new task queue. When I observed the workers in the temporal-UI I see the same worker id for both the task queues.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In many production scenarios, a single Worker is not sufficient, and people run a pool of multiple Workers, each with the same Workflows and/or Activities registered, and polling the same Task Queue.

To tell when a single Worker isn't sufficient, you can look at metrics:

https://docs.temporal.io/application-development/worker-performance

> Worker a single threaded or multi-threaded process?

It depends on which SDK. The Java SDK has multi-threaded Workers: see for example

https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.temporal/temporal-sdk/1.7.0/io/temporal/worker/WorkerFactoryOptions.Builder.html#setMaxWorkflowThreadCount-int-

You can give different Worker instances different identities with:

https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.temporal/temporal-sdk/1.7.0/io/temporal/client/WorkflowClientOptions.Builder.html#setIdentity-java.lang.String-

Comment: Thanks Loren for the explanation. Does creating 2 workers using WorkerFactory in the same process adds any advantage vs single worker listening on task queue having all the workflows?

What I understand from your comment is that Worker process is multi-threaded and threads gets distributed across workers so creating multiple workers in the same process doesn't add any benefit. Is that correct?

Comment: A single Java Worker process will utilize all cores.